# Application for visual collaboration (e.g. story mapping, sticky notes) installed on private server

Tags: collaboration, self-hosted, drawing, privacy, mapping

I'm looking for an application good for building story maps but I need it to be installed on my private server. I know there are multiple great apps available in the public Internet. It does not necessarily be a dedicated story mapping app. Any sticky-notes application is fine. A [miro.com](https://miro.com/) is a cloud-based example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [WeKan](https://wekan.github.io/), it's a [Kanban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development)) board of [Trello](https://trello.com/) style but you can install it on your private server.

With it you can organize information on boards, very visually and with many features such as checklists, labels and filters that help improve productivity using a simple tool.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Good to know it but it's still not suitable for story mapping.